# Error response from daemon while login to Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run Jenkins Pipeline script which will login to Docker and publish my container.

> Updated Pipeline

```
    node {
   echo 'Scm Checkout'

   stage('Scm Checkout'){
       git credentialsId: 'githib', url: 'https://github.com/subhendugn/spring-boot-docker.git', branch: 'master'
   }

   stage('Mvn Package'){
       def mvnHome = tool name: 'Maven3', type: 'maven'
       def mvnCMD =  "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn"
       sh label: '', script: "${mvnCMD} clean package"
   }

   stage('Build Docker Image'){
       sh 'docker build -t subhendugn/spring-boot-docker:latest .'
   }

   stage('Push Docker Image'){
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'docker', variable: 'test_docker')]) {
            sh "docker login -u subhendugn -p ${test_docker} -e subhenduguhaneogi.93@gmail.com https://registry.hub.docker.com"
        }
       sh 'docker push subhendugn/spring-boot-docker:latest'
   }
}
```

but I am getting following error.

> Updated

```
    + docker login -u subhendugn -p **** -e test@gmail.com https://registry.hub.docker.com
WARNING: login credentials saved in /var/lib/jenkins/.dockercfg.
Login Succeeded
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker push subhendugn/spring-boot-docker:latest
The push refers to a repository [subhendugn/spring-boot-docker] (len: 1)
3b9c3c5ae1a5: Buffering to Disk
3b9c3c5ae1a5: Image push failed

Please login prior to push:
Username: EOF
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Can anyone please help me with this? I am looking for hands-on purpose.

Thanks

Comment: you can omit the server when you trying to login to docker hub. For login to some else server, you must specify server. (Docker hub is by default server)

Comment: anyway, you can specify the server when login to docker hub. But actually the registry server is https://registry.hub.docker.com

Answer (score 0):

the http error came from this line,

docker login -u test -p 'test' -e test@gmail.com https://hub.docker.com

you're using a wrong registry url try with:

- https://index.docker.io/v1/ (is implicit, only left blank)
- https://registry.hub.docker.com. (alternative)

If you use https://registry.hub.docker.com (which is a alternative) then you need to retag your image as:

```
docker tag .../... registry.hub.docker.com/.../...
```

then push

```
docker push registry.hub.docker.com/.../...
```

I mean, it now will be not recognized as default, how it is https://index.docker.io/v1/.

So I recommend, left the server blank (implicit) and don't retag.

Comment: Hi @matiferrigno, I tried this ***docker login -u subhendugn -p -e test@gmail.com https://registry.hub.docker.com*** and its working fine now. But getting this error now `Login Succeeded
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker push subhendugn/spring-boot-docker-test:latest
The push refers to a repository [subhendugn/spring-boot-docker-test] (len: 1)
32adf8a0be22: Buffering to Disk
32adf8a0be22: Image push failed

Please login prior to push:
Username: EOF`

Comment: WIthout registry I am not able to login from pipeline script.

Comment: @SubhenduGN I can't read it clearly. But, it seems other trouble Jenkins related. You are using withCredentials Jenkins plugin. Are you using it correctly ? Is not in your original pipeline, but the output shows the plugin in use.

Comment: I means is better if you update your pipeline to understand the new issue.

Comment: Hi @matiferrigno Upated the pipeline code and also latest error what I am getting.

Comment: Hi @SubhenduGN I did some test, if you use the not implicit way for the server you will need retag as I show you. But if you left blank the server, it is taken by default.